# How do I change window title font in Debian 9 with Xfce?

Tags: debian, xfce

I'm running Debian 9with Xfce 4. Window titles look like this after installing a bunch of packages.

[image: Window font in my Debian 9 / Xfce 4]

How do I change it? Going to Settings > Appearance lets me change system font, but that does not change window title font.

Comment: Change it in your xfce theme or choose another theme.

Comment: How do I change it in my xfce theme?

Comment: Google quickly gets me https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1939848

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Xfce has a separate settings for window title font.

[image: Font settings for window title in Xfce]

In Xfce, go to **Settings > Windows Manager > Style**.

- Look for **Title font** with a selectable long button in upper-right area.
- Click on the long button, then a smaller window will appear that allows user to change font family, font style and font size.
- Finally, click **OK** to finish.

The placement of font settings at different location is the norm in Xfce, so user will have to get used to this oddness. Perhaps this actually hints that Xfce prefers to be modular.